# jquery validation for id with s

Tags: jquery

I want to validate a text box to accept only numeric value with ID property starting with 
v1_1,v1_2 etc

Below code validates only with id_1.
How to validate for all the ID_ ?

```
$("#id_1").keydown(function (e) 
    {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write a single keydown event binding code for all input having id stats wiht 'id_...

see below code

```
$("[id^='id_']").keydown(function (e) 
    {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

You can use this selector for name, class or any other attributes. Please see [this](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) link.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`attribute starts with selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/),

```
$("[id^='id_']").keydown(function (e)
```

or the best and the efficient option would be add a common `class` for those elements and use `class selector` rather than using `attribute starts with selector`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `attribute selector ^` for starting with element.

```
$("[id^='id-']").keydown(function (e)
```

The **`[attribute^=value]`** selector is used to select elements whose attribute value begins with a specified value.

Answer (score 0):

use  **[attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**  `^=`

```
$("[id^='id_']").keydown(function (e)
```